# restore untracked and unstaged changes without affecting staged changes

Tags: git

I have a pre-commit hook that runs a script on the whole code base *as if the commit was completed*. To accomplish this I first `git stash -k -u` to stash my unstaged changes and untracked files. Then I run the check (which at this point only contains committed and staged code). Afterwards, I want to put the repo back in the same state it was before. This means the staged changes remain and the working tree is restored to as it was, including untracked files and unstaged changes.

I'm not sure exactly how to do the last part. First I tried `git stash pop`, but this fails when files with staged changes also have unstaged changes. Next I tried `git restore -s stash .` which fixes the previous problem, but doesn't restore the untracked changes. It's as if the `.` in the command refers to the layout of the working tree rather than the layout of source tree. Is this a bug? Is there some other way to accomplish what I'm describing? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. The purpose of the pre-commit hook is to verify that the commit is allowed to be made. For example, it can check the code style. It is an artifact of the current git-commit implementation that any changes made in the hook are picked up by git-commit. But no such guarantee exists and if your hook depends on it, the next Git release can break it.

Comment: No changes are to be made in the hook, only checks. I only want to check that which is going into the commit, not all my unstaged changes or untracked files. They need to be temporarily stored. I can either do that myself, or automate it. The question is about how to automate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a pre-commit hook that runs a script on the whole code base *as if the commit [had been] completed*. To accomplish this I first `git stash -k -u` to stash my unstaged changes and untracked files. Then I run the check (which at this point only contains committed and staged code). Afterwards, I want to put the repo back in the same state it was before.

The recommended method for this is:

```
git reset --hard
git stash pop --index
```

The `pop` step here should always succeed, provided the `git stash push` step did anything in the first place.  That last "provided" means there's an important proviso: you should check to see whether `git stash -k -u` actually *made a stash*, because under some conditions, it does nothing at all.  In this case the `git reset --hard` is unnecessary (but safe as long as your *tests* did not modify anything), and the `git stash pop` *must not be run* since that would pop some *other* stash.

(How do you know whether `git stash push` actually created a stash?  I recommend a two-step `git rev-parse` sequence, which works back into older version of `git stash` where the `push` verb doesn't even exist—where you have to use `git stash save` instead—where you do:

```
old=$(git rev-parse -q --verify refs/stash || true)
git stash push -k -u
new=$(git rev-parse -q --verify refs/stash || true)
```

You can now test whether `$current` and `$new` match as strings:

```
test "$old" != "$new" && do_unstash=true || do_unstash=false
```

for instance.  Now you can condition your final `git stash pop` sequence with:

```
if $do_unstash; then git reset --hard && git stash pop --index; fi
```

If the `push` step made a stash, the outputs of the two `git rev-parse` commands differ: either `$old` is empty and `$new` is non-empty and is the hash ID of the stash, or `$old` is non-empty and `$new` is non-empty and they differ and `$new` is again the hash ID of the stash.  But if `git stash push` decided to do nothing, then either `$old` is empty *and* `$new` is empty, *or* `$old` contains the old top-of-stash-stack hash ID and `$new` contains the same hash ID.

If you have the space for it, though, I'd suggest running the tests on a "clean" `git checkout-index` run in an empty temporary directory, after which you can just remove the empty temporary directory.  This does not require any fancy `git stash` work, and hence functions correctly even when `git stash` has been broken (as it has been in several recent Git versions where, apparently based on questions here on StackOverflow, sometimes `git stash pop` silently fails to restore untracked files).  This also neatly sidesteps all weird corner cases, such as intent-to-add index entries that never actually got added.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its a simple solution to just reset hard and pop, not sure why I didn't think of that. The mind does terrible things (or, more aptly, nothing) late at night. And I was not aware that stash might no-op, I will incorporate that.

Comment: Do you know in what cases `git stash -k -u` fails? It seems like that would only occur when there are no changes to stash. And since this is in a pre-commit `git commit` will fail before the pre-commit is even run, right?

Comment: *It seems like that would only occur when there are no changes to stash.* Right. *And since this is in a pre-commit git commit will fail before the pre-commit is even run, right?* No, because you can use `--allow-empty` here. You could say "just don't do that", of course.:-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is a good answer, but there is `git stash show --only-untracked-v` (no idea why the `--only-untracked` switch even exists), which outputs the diff of only the untracked files in the stash. This diff can be piped into `git apply -`  to recreate the file.

In total...

```sh
git stash show --only-untracked -v | git apply -
```

Comment: The `--only-untracked` option is new in Git 2.32, part of the rewrite of `git stash` in C. In earlier Git versions `git show stash^3` would get similar output; you could also use `git restore` with `stash^3`. In general, though, this isn't the *recommended* method.

Comment: @ktb : to have a better understanding of how a stash is created, you can run `git log --oneline --graph --cc --name-only stash`

Comment: Yeah I definitely will not be using this method. It seems like it would be slow and would remove timestamp metadata.